# View per minute data instead of per second

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel file that shows data for every second interval. I would like to get the data for every minute interval . I dont want average but  a way that it shows data just for every minute eg.(22:06:25 22:07:25 22:06:25 22:08:25 22:06:25 ).

My current data is like this.

```
08.08.2015 22:06:25 114507783   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:25 114507892   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:25 114508002   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:25 114508111   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:25 114508220   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:25 114508329   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:25 114508438   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:25 114508548   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:25 114508657   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:26 114508766   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:26 114508875   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:26 114508984   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:26 114509094   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:26 114509203   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:26 114509312   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:26 114509421   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:26 114509530   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:26 114509640   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:27 114509749   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:27 114509858   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:27 114509967   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:27 114510076   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:27 114510186   1000000 49087   612
08.08.2015 22:06:27 114510295   1000000 49087   612
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does this question even mean? All I see is a block of timestamps, which were apperently created multiple times a second. Do you just want to figure out how to remove time stamps that are from the same minute? What generates these timestamps? Is there other data associated with each row?

Comment: I have updated the data and i want it that it views just per minute as its currently viewing data several times a second

Comment: What do you mean by "views just per minute"? We still don't know where your data is coming from, how can we help?

Comment: The data is from a generator and it records different values(fan speed voltage etc.) 9 times a second and as the data is really large i want that that it just shows what were the values at every minute interval instead of every second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you don't want to / can't change how the number generator actually works. I'll further assume that you dump this data into Excel manually [if you do this automatically through the number generator, this can't be solved without solving at the source number generator]. Therefore, I recommend you have 1 data dump tab, and one review tab.

I further assume for reference that your source tab is called sheet1, and has data in the following columns:

A:A = Date [I assume that this is only run for a single day, and that each day a new Excel file will be created]
B:B = Time
C:C = All other data [if data is in different columns here, adjust the answer below to reflect that]

On your review tab, in A1 simply put the following. Copy down as needed.

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

On B1, put the following:

```
=MIN(Sheet1!B:B)
```

This will pull the lowest timestamp found in Sheet1. Then, on B2 and copied down, put the following:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1+0.001,Sheet1!B:B,1,1)
```

This looks for the time found in the cell above, adding a single minute. If it doesn't find it exactly (matched to the second), it takes the closest appropriate match as your data is sorted.

Put this in C1 and copied down (if your data is also in columns D, E, etc., just copy this formula replacing reference to column C with D, etc - should be able to just copy to the right)

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH($B1,Sheet1!$B:$B,0))
```

This looks for an exact match of the timestamp produced in column B on your new sheet. Then it pulls that data with INDEX onto your new sheet.